# Webpage isn't displayed using WkWebView and Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift2, wkwebview

I am using iOS9 and XCode7.2 to make my app display a webpage using WkWebView and Swift.

To eliminate possible errors, I have created an XCode project that has only the following code and there is nothing in Main.storyboard.

The weird thing is that the webpage only shows up "1 time" after I ran the code over and over the past few days.  Two members on StackOverflow confirmed that the code works for XCode 8 / Swift 3, and Xcode 7.3.1 / iOS 9.3 simulator.

Is my xCode too old or what other problems might cause it?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView!
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.yahoo.com")!
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: add one line in your loadview() thats is  webView.navigationDelegate = self

Comment: when you say the web page only shows up 1 time, do you mean it only worked once and otherwise it's always just a blank screen?

Comment: @BJHStudios , yes

Comment: I see a containerView IBOutlet there, is that linked to anything in your storyboard?

Comment: you are also missing the call to super.loadView() when you override loadView()

Comment: @BJHStudios , I havn't used the IBOutlet anywhere.  But it's odd the webpage actually shows up once without using the IBOutlet.  So I assume I don't need it.

Comment: just trying to make sure there isn't something leftover in your storyboard accidentally covering the view. This isn't how I would've implemented it, but I have your code running in XCode 8 / Swift 3 w/o issue

Comment: @ BJHStudios , Thanks.  As a newbie, I get confused of examples I found online.  How do I distinguish which example is for which version?

Comment: Your code works for me in Xcode 7.3.1 and iOS 9.3 simulator

Comment: @BJHStudios , How would you implement the webpage?

Comment: I would probably either go the container view route or add it as a subview, but, as always, there are many roads to Rome.

Comment: @BJHStudios , Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Step : 1** Import webkit in ViewController.swift

```
import WebKit
```

**Step : 2** Declare variable of webView.

```
var webView : WKWebView!
```

**Step : 3** Adding Delegate of WKNavigationDelegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , WKNavigationDelegate{
```

**Step : 4** Adding code in ViewDidLoad.

```
let myBlog = "https://www.google.com/"
let url = NSURL(string: myBlog)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

// init and load request in webview.

webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.loadRequest(request)
self.view.addSubview(webView)
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(webView)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way with auto layout for all device:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

let webView = WKWebView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupWebView()
}

fileprivate func setupWebView() {
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.apple.com") else { return }
        self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}}
```

in info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```